# Paging & panels

Tags: paging

I have a site with a front page that is built up with different blocks; some of these have paging activated. They work great because they are Ajax controlled.

When you scroll all the way down to the bottom, use the pagination, and change page, the blocks change page too, and end up to the same page.
I would love to have my panel to react in such a way that when you change the page using the pager at the bottom, the blocks don't change page too.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to ensure that each pager has a different pager id. Normally, you only have page=X in the url, but if several blocks "listen" to that, you get this behaviour. If your blocks comes from Views, then there is a pager setting for setting an alternate pager id, which exists specifically to work around this.

If your pagers come from a different module, you will have to open an issue with that module about how to change the pager id.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Ajax pagination too in the bottom panel; it won't conflict again.

Comment: Hmm .. will give it a try :) but i've read somewhere that it will do no good to searchmachine indexation and it is hard to cache those ( i am not using drupal cache but APC)